# The sacrificial perogative of the kings of Israel

Tags: exegesis, sacrifice, 1-samuel, saul

Why was the sacrifice offered by Saul at Gilgal rejected by God while obviously the sacrifices of David and Solomon at a later time were evidently accepted? Did it have anything to do with the death of Samuel?

Comment: Saul specifically disobeyed Samuel's instructions to wait for Samuel. As far as I know, David and Solomon both sacrificed with the approval of the high priest. This is a good question though, it is a little uncertain in some cases.

Comment: There are probably different perspectives on this question -- is there a particular tradition or denomination whose views you would like?

Answer (score 1):

I would add to the above explanation that Saul was offering a sacrifice while being in rebellion to the command to kill everyone and destroy the spoil.
1Sa 15:3  Now go and smite Amalek, and utterly destroy all that they have, and spare them not; but slay both man and woman, infant and suckling, ox and sheep, camel and ass.' 
This should be a warning to us that we can't offer sacrifice while in rebellion and expect it to be accepted.